# AWS Athena: Querying by an attributes of a struct with an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I crawled data using aws glue to import json data from an s3 folder that contains data where the  root braces is an array like this:

```
[{id: '1', name: 'rick'},{id: '2', name: 'morty'}]
```

This ends up resulting in a schema like this:

```
array<struct<expand:string,id:string,name:string>>
```

**How do I query by `name` in Athena?**

If I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM people_s3_buckets WHERE name = "rick";
```

I get the following error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: Column 'name' cannot be resolved
```

**Perhaps, there is a way to setup the Glue crawler to add just the elements within the array and avoid the nesting alltogether?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to query fields of elements within an array, you would need to `UNNEST` it first. Assuming that structure `array<struct<expand:string,id:string,name:string>>` corresponds to column `members`, you would need to do

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    people_s3_buckets,
    UNNEST(members) as t(member)
WHERE
    member.name = 'rick'
```

Note, you need to use single quotes instead fo double quotes.

Here is the official AWS docs on handling arrays in AWS Athena: [Querying Arrays](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/querying-arrays.html)